# Is there any change in Xcode 12.0 that changes ButtonType from roundedRect to system?

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, xcode12

I recently update Xcode from V11.x to V12.0, and had to fix App that just added outlet property to text field but the storyboard got changed buttonType from 'roundedRect' to 'system'. Attached below screen image.

[image: Github Changed file summary]

Answer (score 4):

There are no rounded rect  buttons on iOS. They ended several years ago. A system button was used instead. So now they’ve stopped using the name too.

Comment: Does that also mean behaviour/UI remains unchanged on App?

Comment: FYI - indeed there was impact on text fields background colour tuned to screen colour by default. I had to recompile on 11.7v to get it right(white). Alternatively I could have change background colour for all the text fields across app to white and compile on 12v.